# How to update dataframe partially

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [1,1,1,1], 'col2' = [2,2,2,2]}, index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

I have separate procedure to fix some values of DataFrame above. As result I receive other DataFrame with col1:

```
df_col1_updated = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [2,3]}, index = ['a', 'c])
```

What I really need - to update the column col1 with keys 'a' and 'c' by values from df_col1_updated:

```
pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [2,1,3,1], 'col2' = [2,2,2,2]}, index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try [pandas.DataFrame.update()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

```
df.update(df_col1_updated)
```

This modifies df in place

```
    col1   col2
a   2.0    2
b   1.0    2
c   3.0    2
d   1.0    2
```